# UITableView showing black screen and grey bottom

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitableviewsectionheader

[This is What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oriJS.jpg) Table View is in

I am using Firebase for Authentication, when I logout and Login again to the app with the account, I get this error.

**This is my TabBarViewController (UITabBarController)**

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpScreens()
        
    }
    
    private func setUpScreens() {
        guard let currentEmail = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email") else { return }
        
        let home = HomeScreen()
        home.title = "Home"
        let profile = ProfileScreen(currentEmail: currentEmail)
        profile.title = "Profile"
        
        home.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        profile.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        
        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: home)
        let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profile)
        
        nav1.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        nav2.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        nav1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "house"), tag: 1)
        nav2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), tag: 2)
        
        setViewControllers([nav1, nav2 ], animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

**This is my Profile Screen where the tableview is present**

```
//
//  ProfileScreen.swift
//  EzyBlogger
//
//  Created by M. Ahmad Ali on 20/06/2023.
//

import UIKit
import Photos
import PhotosUI

class ProfileScreen: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    //    Profile Picture
    
    //    Full Name
    
    //    Email
    
    //    List of Blog Posts
    
    //MARK: - Defining UI Elements
    
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Defining variables
    let currentEmail: String
    private var user: User?
    
    init(currentEmail: String) {
        self.currentEmail = currentEmail
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    //MARK: - View Functions
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        setUpSignOut()
        setUpTableView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    //MARK: - SignOut Functionality
    
    private func setUpSignOut() {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Sign Out",
            style: .done,
            target: self, action: #selector(didTapSignOut))
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapSignOut() {
        let alertSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Out", message: "Are you sure you'd like to sign out?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: .destructive) { _ in
            AuthManager.shared.signOut { [weak self] success in
                if success {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "email")
                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "name")
                        let signInVC = SignInScreen()
                        signInVC.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
                        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: signInVC)
                        navVC.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
                        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                        self?.present(navVC,animated: true)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("not logged out")
                }
            }
        }
        
        alertSheet.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertSheet, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - Table View
    
    private func setUpTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        setUpTableHeader()
        fetchProfileData()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    }
    
    private func setUpTableHeader(profilePicRef: String? = nil, name: String? = nil) {
        let width = view.bounds.width
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(
            x: 0, y: 0,
            width: width, height: width/1.5 )
        )
        headerView.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        headerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        headerView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        //        Profile Picture
        let profilePic = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "person.circle"))
        profilePic.tintColor = .white
        profilePic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profilePic.frame = CGRect(
            x: (width-(width/4))/2,
            y: (headerView.bounds.height-(width/4))/2.5,
            width: width/4, height: width/4
        )
        profilePic.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        headerView.addSubview(profilePic)
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapProfilePic))
        profilePic.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
        //        Email
        let emailLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
            x: 20, y: profilePic.bounds.maxY+52,
            width: width-40, height: 100)
        )
        
        headerView.addSubview(emailLabel)
        emailLabel.text = currentEmail
        emailLabel.textColor = .white
        emailLabel.textAlignment = .center
        emailLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold)
        
        //        Name
        if let name = name {
            title = name
        }
        if let ref = profilePicRef {
            //            Fetch Image
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        var contentConfig = UIListContentConfiguration.cell()
        contentConfig.text = "Title of Cell"
        cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfig
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    //MARK: - Setting Up Profile
    
    private func fetchProfileData() {
        DBManager.shared.getUser(email: currentEmail) { [weak self] user in
            guard let user = user else {return}
            self?.user = user
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.setUpTableHeader(
                    profilePicRef: user.profilePictureRef,
                    name: user.name
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapProfilePic() {
        guard let myEmail = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email"),
              myEmail == currentEmail else { return }
        openPHPicker()
    }
    
}

extension ProfileScreen: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: .none)
        picker.isEditing = true
        results.forEach { result in
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { reading, error in
                guard let image = reading as? UIImage, error == nil else { return }
                StorageManager.shared.uploadProfilePicture(
                    email: self.currentEmail,
                    image: image
                ) { success in
                    if success {
                        
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func openPHPicker() {
           var phPickerConfig = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
           phPickerConfig.selectionLimit = 1
           phPickerConfig.filter = PHPickerFilter.any(of: [.images, .livePhotos])
           let phPickerVC = PHPickerViewController(configuration: phPickerConfig)
           phPickerVC.delegate = self
           present(phPickerVC, animated: true)
       }
    
}
```

**How can I solve this Problem?**

My Xcode version is 14.3.x
My Swift version is 5.8.1

**I have tried**

1. to create another account to login
2. Change the TableView's Background Color
3. Remove and add tableView Again
4. Uninstall and install the app again
5. Erase simulator data
6. Clean the build folder with ( Shift + cmd + K )